# EF Code First limit foreign Key Insert/Updates to a given ReferenceType

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first

Fairly new to EF Code First and trying to workout how to do something I have normally done with triggers. I am wanting to create a reference table that contains various items for different dropdowns and selection boxes in a given system. Layout of reference table is as follows:

```
    ReferenceId     Guid
    ReferenceType   string
    Key             string
    value           object
```

I would like to store key/values for items like status codes, sex type, whatever multiple choice selections the user comes up with. I would like to have a foreign key set on different tables to where the key/value exists in reference table before allowing insert/updates. I have done this in the past in Database First SQL by creating a foreign key and then adding a trigger to limit allowed key/value belonging to a specific ReferenceType.

As far as I'm aware you do not have triggers with EF Code First, so I am thinking I will need to perform a check in the set method of the foreign key id property for a given table to make sure the value is of given ReferenceType in reference table and throw an exception if not. I'm thinking of a method in reference table model that a set method in another table model could call passing ReferenceType and Key and if valid getting the ReferenceId returned otherwise a null and throwing an exception.

My question is if this is the right way about handling this type of situation or is there another way in EF to perform this that I'm not seeing?

*Currently coding for Net Core 2.2*

Comment: I'm thinking these two documents might help me out [_Tutorial: Learn about advanced scenarios - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/advanced?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [_Tutorial: Implement inheritance - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using custom validation attribute. Found that I needed to override both `SaveChanges()` and `SaveChangesAsync()` in my DBContext. Added a call to the following method:

```
        private void ValidateEntities()
        {
            var entities = (from entry in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                            where entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added
                            select entry.Entity);

            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
                Validator.ValidateObject(entity, validationContext, true);
            }
        }
```

This allowed me to apply the following `ValidationAttribute` class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using DataAccess.Models;

namespace DataAccess.Data.Attributes
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Valid Reference Attribute
    /// </summary>
    /// <revision>
    /// __Revisions:__~~
    /// | Contributor | Build | Revison Date | Description |~
    /// |-------------|-------|--------------|-------------|~
    /// | Christopher D. Cavell | 0.3.0 | 09/16/2019 | Initial commit |~ 
    /// </revision>
    public sealed class ValidGenderTypeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private Guid validGuid = Constants.GenderTypeId; 

        /// <summary>
        /// Validate ReferenceTypeId
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value">object</param>
        /// <param name="validationContext">ValidationContext</param>
        /// <returns>ValidationResult</returns>
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value is Reference)
                {
                    Reference reference  = (Reference)value;

                    if (reference.ReferenceTypeId == validGuid)
                        return ValidationResult.Success;

                    return new ValidationResult($"Invalid GenderTypeID: {reference.ReferenceTypeId.ToString()}");  
                }
                return new ValidationResult($"Invalid object type: {value.GetType().ToString()}");
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

to my model like so:

```
        /// <value>Guid</value>
        public Guid? GenderId { get; set; }

        /// <value>Reference</value>
        [ForeignKey("GenderId")]
===>    [ValidGenderType]
        public Reference Gender { get; set; }
```